# Java Swing Window is Too Tall

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

I am building a small application using Java Swing. The application will be used on several different computers. I am using a GridLayout. The problem is that the window is not adjustable since I show the gui like this:

```
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    addComponentsToPane(getContentPane());
    pack();
    setVisible(true);
```

I am aware that pack() is causing this. The program works fine on my computer but the window is relatively tall. On some other computers the bottom is cut off so that the user cannot access some features. What is the best solution for this? I have thought of several approaches but none of them seem optimal:

1. Rearrange the window so that this is not a problem.
2. Add a scroll bar.

Unfortunately, I would like to keep the window structured as it is since it looks nice and is intuitive. I already have scroll bars for some selectors so I think adding a scroll bar for the window will look very cluttered and add confusion.

I would appreciate any suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: `JScrollPane` would seem to be the logic solution, but that would depend on what the UI currently looks like and how it's built

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to add a scroll bar, and you don't want to rearrange the widgets, then the only options left are

1. Lay the items out on more than one window (two pages for example).
2. Change the scaling of the items (shrink them)

There is not an infinite number of approaches.  The more approaches you decide are unsuitable will limit the opportunities to address the key issues.  In your case, you have two dramatically different screen layouts, the obvious solution would be to detect the screen parameters, and select one of two different layouts, each tailored to look good.

Answer (score 1):

Too much controls in a window is much boring. So why don't you categorize the controls and add them in different tabs using JTabbedPane ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more suitable. If this is not desired, then adding a scroll pane would be better. Well shrinking the controls may not be that helpful